# Can I put 2 disks into a raid-0 array without reformatting the FS?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm

We have an existing /dev/sda disk; we are adding an identical /dev/sdb

I want to place these two disks in a raid-0 array.

Can I do that without reformatting /dev/sda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. But you can create a RAID-0 array containing *only* /dev/sdb, copy the data from /dev/sda to /dev/md0 , *then* add /dev/sda to the array. Voila, data preserved!

Comment: Note that you don't *format* sda, you just add it to the array.

Comment: @psusi: Good point, edited.